# Highcharts last point sometimes is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, highcharts

I have a graph with data that is updated constantly. Most of the time the graph is fine, but sometimes the circle image of the last point is hidden, and it's properties are different from the others. In case that its not hidden, the properties is similar to the others except x and y coordinates.

Invalid graph
The first two image tags is correct, and the last one is incorrect and is hidden

```
<image preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/marker-green.png" x="62" y="127.47" width="22" height="22" transform="translate(-11,-11)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#a2b955" r="0"></image>

<image preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/marker-green.png" x="0" y="109.47999999999999" width="22" height="22" transform="translate(-11,-11)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#a2b955" r="0"></image>

<image preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/marker-green.png" x="866.0000000000001" y="208" width="22" height="22" transform="translate(-9,-9)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" fill="#a2b955" r="2" visibility="hidden"></image>
```

[image: Invalid graph]

Valid graph
The first image tag is the last circle point

```
<image preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/marker-green.png" x="867" y="210" width="22" height="22" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#a2b955" r="0" transform="translate(-11,-11)"></image>  

<image preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/marker-green.png" x="810" y="210" width="22" height="22" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#a2b955" r="0" transform="translate(-11,-11)"></image>  

<image preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/marker-green.png" x="752" y="209.16" width="22" height="22" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#a2b955" r="0" transform="translate(-11,-11)"></image>
```

[image: Valid graph]

---

What can be the cause of the hidden property? Outer div is big and CSS is properly. Thank you.

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question rather than including a screenshot of your code.

Comment: Post was edited, added actual code and printscreen

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? It should not happen, unless you specified some options to do that, for example `xAxis.max` or using `xAxis.setExtremes()`.